# Layer system for images on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, image, graphics, wpf-controls

I am trying to figure out how I can have a layer system for my app. I am adding images to an `itemscontrol` and they are all rendering one on top of the other.

```
                <ItemsControl Name="canvasDataBinding"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Height="512"
                                    Width="512" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    ClipToBounds="True">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Background="Transparent"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Name}"
                                    Width="{Binding Width}"
                                    Height="{Binding Height}">
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

For testing purposes, I tried adding `Panel.Zindex="{Binding Zind}"` inside the image control, and decrementing `Zind` every time a new image was added to the collection, but the images still render on top of each other.

I also thought about having multiple collections, each collection would be its own layer. I dont know how I would implement this with my current code though.

Edit:
I added an ItemContainerStyle:

```
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Zindex}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Again I am binding the value of ZIndex to an int that I decrement before the image is added to the collection. It is still rendering one on top of the other.

Comment: You need to set your `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Left`, and `Panel.ZIndex` in the `ItemContainerStyle` so the property so it gets applied to the `<ContentPresenter>` that wraps each Image. See the bottom of [this](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) post on my blog for a more detailed explanation and an example.

Comment: @Rachel I edited my post with your suggestion, Im still having trouble. Also why would I need to set Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left though?

Comment: `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` tell WPF where to draw each item. If you're using a `Canvas` as the ItemsPanel, then all items will be drawn at 0,0 unless you specify otherwise, which is why they're all being drawn on top of each other

Comment: @Rachel I left out most of the code to simply my post. I will be more careful next time. Anyway I got it working by just setting the Panel.ZIndex in the ItemContainerStyle like you mentioned. I just forgot to update my constructor. Thanks.

Comment: Ah good to know, I'll post that as an answer then. I was going to earlier but didn't have time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Left`, and `Panel.ZIndex` in the `ItemContainerStyle` so the property gets applied to the `<ContentPresenter>` that wraps each Image.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Zindex}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

When your `ItemsControl` gets rendered, it actually renders like this

```
<Canvas>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Image />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Image />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Image />
    </ContentPresenter>
</Canvas>
```

which is why it doesn't work to set the property on the `<Image>` itself.